# Good way of playing video in AR with an alpha channel?

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to enable alpha channel on a video using AFrame.

I'm using "transparent" set to true but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Any ideas?

```
a-scene>
  <a-assets timeout="30000">
    <video id="lyrics" autoplay loop="true" transparent="true" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/d70cd89d-5883-430e-aa23-db6ffd90c2e4%2Fconverted.webm?v=1610981890345">
    
  </a-assets>
  
  <a-camera position="0 1.2 0"></a-camera>
  
  <!-- Environment for 2D and VR viewing. It's auto-hidden in AR mode. -->
  <a-entity environment="preset: forest; lighting: none; shadow: none; lightPosition: 0 2.15 0"
            hide-in-ar-mode></a-entity>
  
  <a-video src="#lyrics" width="2" height="1.375" position="0 -1 -2"></a-video>
  
  <a-entity light="type: ambient; intensity: 0.5;"></a-entity>
  <a-light type="directional"
           light="castShadow: true;
                  shadowMapHeight: 1024;
                  shadowMapWidth: 1024;
                  shadowCameraLeft: -7;
                  shadowCameraRight: 5;
                  shadowCameraBottom: -5;
                  shadowCameraTop: 5;"
           id="light"
           target="dino"
           position="-5 3 1.5"></a-light>

  <!-- This shadow-receiving plane is only visible in AR mode. -->
  <a-plane height="15" width="15" position="0 0 -3" rotation="-90 0 0"
           shadow="receive: true"
           ar-shadows="opacity: 0.3"
           visible="false"></a-plane>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specifically tell the material to use an `THREE.RGBAFormat` - therefore utilizing the alpha channel in the `.webm`. It's quite simple:

```
// after the entity is loaded, eg. el.addEventListener("loaded", e => {})
// grab the meshes material.
let material = this.el.getObject3D("mesh").material;

// switch the format to THREE.RGBAFormat
material.map.format = THREE.RGBAFormat;

// force an material update
material.map.needsUpdate = true;
```

And if all goes well, you should see the `.webm` being rendered correctly:
[image]

You can check it out [here](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/arjs/webm_video.html) - works on Windows10 and mobile (android).

---

I'd strongly recommend troubleshooting `arjs` by re-creating the scene with vanilla `a-frame`. It's possible the issue is shared, and in my experience it's easier to debug. For example [here](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/webm_alpha_material.html) is the same scene with the `webm` video.

Comment: thanks so much for your help! i tried this code out in glitch and its playing in the browser, but not on my android phone. same with your test it seems.

Comment: @EdInky it seems to be working on my phone - https://imgur.com/a/u99xdfO - Do you have a link to the glitch? also - is the video pitch black?

Comment: thanks so much for the help! i managed to get it working.

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: i discoverd that it won't autoplay on mobile, but will in the browser, so i added a little play button.